# Python simplejsonでunicodeのjsonを扱う('ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: ordinal not in range(128))

Tags: python, json

Pythonで下記のようなutf8のjsonをファイルから読み込んで表示しましたが、下記エラーのため表示できませんでした。

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "idx": 1,
        "text": "あああああ"
    }
]
```

エラー

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./index.cgi", line 23, in <module>
    print d['text']
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

idとidxは問題なく表示されますがtextはこのエラーが出ます。どのようにすれば表示できるのでしょうか。

jsonの扱いはsimplejsonで下記のようにファイルを読み込んでいます。

```
f = open('sample.json', 'r')
data = json.load(f)
```

PythonはPython2.5.1です。
よろしくお願いします。

index.cgi

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#coding:utf-8


import sys
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()
try:
    import json
except ImportError:
    import simplejson as json

print 'Content-Type: text/html\n'
print

f = open('sample.json', 'r')
data = json.loads(f.read().decode('utf-8'))
f.close()


for d in data:
    print d['text']

#print json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf8')
```

Comment: エラーはindex.cgiで出ています。index.cgiを貼ってもらえますか？

Comment: index.cgiを追加しました。

Comment: コードに問題はありません。私の環境では問題なく動きました。環境変数が匂います。LANG/LC_CTYPE/LC_ALL あたりの環境変数がどのような値になっているか教えてもらえますか？

Comment: LANG=ja_JP.UTF-8, LC_CTYPEはなし, LC_ALL=Cでした。

Comment: `$ LC_ALL= python index.cgi` とした時は動きますか？

Comment: 試してみましたが同様のエラーで動きませんでした。

Comment: [このディスカッションをチャットで続行](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39052/discussion-between-ernix-and-zousan)しましょう。

Comment: 下の回答のコメントで解決できました。ありがとうございました

Answer (score 1, accepted):

文字コードを指定してファイルを読む必要があります．

```
import codecs

f = codecs.open('sample.json', 'r', 'utf-8')
data = json.load(f)
```

としてみて下さい．

Comment: 同じエラーで表示できませんでした。

Comment: `load`の引数にエンコードを指定できますか? `load(f, 'utf-8')` または `load(f, encoding='utf-8')` みたいに．
またはいったん`utf-8`でデコードしたユニコード文字列を読みこむのはどうですか? `data = json.loads(open('sample.json', 'r').read().decode('utf-8'))`のよう

Comment: すべての方法を試しましたが解決できません。

Comment: エラーが出ているのは`print`文で，jsonはロードできているがユニコード文字列をそのままprintしようとしてエラーがでている?

Comment: そのとおりです。

Comment: print文はstr型でなければならないのでユニコード文字列を特定の文字コードでエンコードします`utf-8`で出力するなら`print d['text'].encode('utf-8')`

Comment: この方法でできました。ありがとうございます。